# How to make an action method render a particular named view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this action method SearchAroundMe(), and then one thinks that it will render the view "NoViewHasThisName", but to my surprise the method insist on rendering the default view "SearchAroundMe", **How to make the action method render the "NoViewHasThisName" view?**

I have uploaded a simple test application to Skydrive with this problem: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=5c0bc0a6f7bdc3c6#cid=5C0BC0A6F7BDC3C6&id=5C0BC0A6F7BDC3C6%21164

If you just run the application you will see the problem. Because I am using a location aware browser, the app will ask allowance to track your physical position, don't worry about this, as I am not collecting any information or doing anything bad.

```
**[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult SearchAroundMe(double latitude, double longitude) 
{ 
    return View("NoViewHasThisName"); 
}**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Brandon, your observations yesterday was very important in tracking down the problem. I found the solution to the problem. Using jQuery.post() caused some problems, but when I switched to transport the data from the view to the controller using **form submit**, suddenly there was no problens anymore :-)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchAroundMe","News")) 
{        
        @Html.Hidden("latitude");
        @Html.Hidden("longitude");
}

var latField = $("#latitude");
var longField = $("#longitude");

latField.val(latitude);
longField.val(longitude);

$('form').submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing an ajax post, but you're not actually doing anything with the result.

You're not leaving the page at all. Take a look at Firebug after you allow your location, it performs the post and it returns the view "NoViewHasThisName", but you don't see it because you haven't defined what to do with the result.

Replace your `.post` call with this and you'll see what I mean

```
    $.ajax("News/SearchAroundMe", {
      type: "POST",
      async: false,
      data: { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude },
      success: function (response) {
          $("body").html(response);
      }
    });
```

Obviously this isn't exactly what you want to do, but it's just an example.

Comment: Hi Brandon, thank you, your observation is very interesting to me, I am still thinking about how I can leave the initial "SearchAroundMe" view behind and render the result in the "NoViewHasThisName" view?

Comment: @rune007, pretty much how I showed you. Maybe make your POST action return a PartialResult (which means no `<html><head>` etc. tags. Maybe just a view that returns a Search Results div. Then use jQuery to swap out the content section, as I did with the body.

Comment: Hm... Is it not possible to return a different view from my controller? I have to do some jQuery stuff? Have to go soon, North Europe is getting late.

Comment: @rune007, You are returning a different view from the controller. But because it is an ajax action, you have to do something with the result. Partial Views with jQuery is nice and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the path to the `NoViewHasThisName.aspx` view you want to return:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult SearchAroundMe(double latitude, double longitude) 
{ 
    return View("~/Views/NoViewHasThisName.aspx"); 
}
```

Comment: Hi amurra, just tried to write return View("~/Views/NoViewHasThisName.cshtml"), but still the problem is the same I get the "SearchAroundMe" view and not the "NoViewHasThisName" view. Try it yourself with my test app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller");
```

And create an empty action :

```
public ActionResult NoViewHasThisName()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Hi Toc, I tried to write RedirectToAction("NoViewHasThisName", "News") in my controller, but it had no effect. Is it perhaps impossible to return a different view from my controller? Have to go now, getting late in North Europe.

Comment: Did you create the action "NoViewHasThisName" in the controller News?

Comment: Yes I did, the situation is a little special, you can see it more if you run the test app, linked to in the initial post, you can also look at the answers from Brandon, because he has spotted the source of the problem. How I return the right view, though, is still not solved.